# Parent process kill() child process but then doesn't respond to read() or printf()?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, kill

When the child process executing the program a is sent the signal SIGTERM, it should output to the stdout just before terminating. But my read() in (signal == 1) is running? I get no output from the  printf function. When the signal is sent, the parents seems to just finish?

The "a" program will print to stdout put when it is sent the input or when it is terminated using by flushing and signal handling.

```
int pid, childpid;
int fd1[2], fd2[2];
pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);
input = 10;

for (int signal = 0; signal < 2; signal++) {
    input = input + 2;
    char str[20];

    if (signal == 0) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (pid == 0) {
            //child process
            childpid = getpid();
            dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd1[0]);
            close(fd1[1]);
            close(fd2[0]);
            int err;
            if ((err = execlp("./a", "./a", NULL)) < 0) { printf("HELP"); }
        }
        else {
            close(fd1[0]);
            close(fd2[1]);
            write(fd1[1], &input, sizeof(input));
            sleep(2);
            int nbytes = read(fd2[0], str, sizeof(str));
            printf("%d\n", nbytes);
        }
    }
    
   
    if (signal == 1) {
        write(fd1[1], &input, sizeof(input));
        kill(childpid, SIGTERM);
        printf("NOTHING IS PRINTING HERE\n");
        

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to test the return value from any of the `exec*()` family of functions.  If it succeeds, it doesn't return; if it returns, it failed.  And if it does return, you should probably stop executing there — using `exit()` or `_exit()` or something similar.  Also, error messages should be printed to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and messages should end with a newline in general.

Comment: We would need a [mre] to answer the question.  But my crystal ball tells me that program `a` is using `printf()` to write its output, and that output is still buffered when the `SIGTERM` arrives.

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: You need to show the code for your program `a` so we can see why you think the output should appear when it receives SIGTERM.  By default, SIGTERM abruptly terminates the process — no buffers are flushed, etc.  Hence, you need to provide a MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name), as you've already been told.

Comment: My main problem is that the printf function doesn't run at all? I get nothing from it nor does the read() function.

Comment: Do you need a *third* person to ask you for a minimal, reproducible example?  I'm sure one will come along eventually, but you'll avoid closure and get an answer sooner if you don't wait for that.

Comment: very new to stack overflow sorry so I don't really understand how things work. I edited the code. The printf() after the kill() function doesn't do anything...

Comment: In the parent `childpid` is never initialized, so attempting to pass it as an argument in `kill(childpid, SIGTERM);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you seeing output from `printf("%d\n", nbytes);`?  I suspect that the failure to close all the file descriptors is causing the parent to block on the `read` just before that, but it's impossible to say without seeing the code for `./a`.  But with the UB in the invalid reference to `childpid` in the parent, all speculation is pointless.

Comment: You don't test whether the function calls succeed properly.  For example, how do you know whether the write calls succeeded?  How do you know whether the signal was sent successfully?  And what does the `a` program do?  We can't help you debug the code we can't see!

Answer (score 0):

You expect your `execlp` call to return a value when the execution is over/interrupted, that won't happen.

From the [execlp documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ccompiler/doc/lr2/execlp.htm):

> A successful call to execlp does not have a return value because the new process image overlays the calling process image. However, a -1 is returned if the call to execlp is unsuccessful.

Simply put, if the program runs, `execlp` won't return.

Comment: Although it's true that `execlp` does not return on success, I don't think that the `printf("HELP");` is what the OP is asking about.